# What is an alternative for New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue() in CSOM Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell

I want to get the display name of created by and modified by fields for a user in a SharePoint 2013 List using CSOM in powershell.

I know that can be acheived by:

```
New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue()
```

But I want an alternative for that in CSOM powershell. Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint CSOM, use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue class instead like this:

```
$owner = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue($item["Owner"]).LookupValue
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this for Author and Editor columns in a list.

```
function GetUserDisplayName($UserValue)
{
    $user = $web.SiteUsers.GetById($UserValue.Split(";#")[0]);      
    return $user.DisplayName
}
```

Comment: Thanks @newbie what value to provide in $UserValue?

Comment: You can you a user column type. Such as Author or Editor columns for a list item.

Comment: This is not CSOM though...

Comment: Ooops yea. I saw PowerShell SharePoint-Server labels :/